# Compare column names of multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

In the below code, I created list of dataframes. Now I want to check if all the dataframes in `dataframes` list has same column names (I just want to compare headers, not the values) and if the condition is not met, it should error out.

```
dataframes = []
list_of_files = os.listdir(os.path.join(folder_location, quarter, "inputs"))
for files in list_of_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder_location, quarter, "inputs", files), header=[0,1], sheetname= "Ratings Inputs", parse_cols ="B:AC", index_col=None).reset_index()
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(df.columns.names)]
                                       + list(df.columns)[1:])

    dataframes.append(df)
```

Comment: Can you do a single loop and compare the current_dataframe.columns with dataframe[0].columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it will get you there:

```
np.all([sorted(dataframes[0].columns) == sorted(i.columns) for i in dataframes])
```

`sorted` serves the purpose of both transforming into lists and making sure they dont fail because they are in different order